# How to get xpath for dropdown button which contains an "edit" link?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am not having much luck with this xpath stuff :-( I'm trying to click on a dropdown button which contains an "Edit" link. Can you please help. HTML below

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
<span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
   <li><a href="/message/edit/958046" class="edit-message-link">Edit</a></li>
   <li><a href="/message/remove/958046" class="remove-message-link">Delete</a></li>
   <li>
      <a href="/message/enable-replies/958046" class="enable-replies-link hidden">Enable replies</a>
      <a href="/message/disable-replies/958046" class="disable-replies-link">Disable replies</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At any point the edit link has to be visible in order to use the following selector. Since, I always prefer using *css* over *xpath* I provided you both options. Notice, these are partial search based on **href** value

Css

```
a[href^='/message/edit']
```

Xpath

```
//a[contains(@href,'/message/edit')]
```

Comment: You are right. i just tried it and got the following error: Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with. I need to click the dropdown-toggle button based on whether it contains "Edit" or not.

Comment: @ratsstack Try performing a click on dropdown menu and use any explicit wait if needed

Comment: Can you please provide the xpath/css for clicking the dropdown toggle based on the "Edit" link being an item in the menu? Thanks

Comment: @ratsstack try this css `ul[role='menu']>li>a[href^='/message/edit']`

Comment: @ratsstack  xpath `//ul[@role='menu']//a[contains(@href,'/message/edit')]`

Comment: Unfortunately both didn't work. First returned "element is not currently visible" and the second returned "no such element"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75160/discussion-between-ratsstack-and-saifur).